# Can't attach files from form using phpMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I need send an email with attachments (words, pdf...) from a Contact form.

The email is sent well, but with .pdf not attached and with .docx I have a file without extension (choosing office to run it looks perfectly) 
This is my code:

```
<form  method="post" action="components/trabajamail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" accept="application/pdf,application/msword">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
```

My php file based on [This](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps):

```
$mail = new PHPMAILER ();

    $mail->setFrom ( 'from@mail.com', 'Mailer' ); // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress ( 'to@mail.com' );
    $mail->isHTML ( true ); // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
    $mail->Body = "Message";
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    // Attach the uploaded file
    if (array_key_exists ( 'userfile', $_FILES )) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam ( sys_get_temp_dir (), sha1 ( $_FILES ['userfile'] ['name'] ) );
        if (move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['userfile'] ['tmp_name'], $uploadfile )) {
            $mail->addAttachment ( $uploadfile, 'File' );
        }
    }

    if (! $mail->send ()) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'><strong>Error!</strong></div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Success!</strong></div>";
    }
```

The last if never show me nothing, but i cant find the problem

I have read some threads with similar problems and I have used examples from the officinal page but I do not get this to work

Comment: please provide uploaded file with file exist path.

Comment: Check your return values, for example that `addAttachment` succeeds. Check that the `$_FILES` superglobal contains what you think it should.